# Mathematical notation of a sorted array/list/set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I have an array of numbers $A = [3, 5.01, 0.008, 899, 0.23,...]$, which I need to sort, i.e.
$A_{sorted} = \text{sort}(A) = [0.008, 0.23, 3, 5.01, 899,\dots]$.

What is the notation to indicate both $A$ and $A_{sorted}$, and the "*$\text{sort}$*" operation? Also, is there any compact notation for sorted arrays? (...by chance, any book/reference about notations for sorted arrays/lists/sets?...) - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Increasing sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mathematician would be more likely to talk about a (finite or infinite) sequence, $A = \langle a_0,a_1,\dotsc\rangle$, rather than an array. Or possibly about the set of numbers $A=\{a_0,a_1,\dotsc\}$.

Then they might say "reindex the sequence $A$ in monotone increasing order as $B=\langle b_0, b_1,\dotsc\rangle$." In the case of an infinite sequence you need to show that it's well-ordered.

With a set, order doesn't matter anyway. They might just say "index the elements of $A$ in monotone increasing order." Then it would be understood that $a_0$ now refers to the smallest element, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) You used the bra-ket notation to indicate a sequence.. However, I have seen people use the round parenthesis for sequences.. Which one is more common for sequences ? Can I also use round parenthesis?

Comment: You can if you want! In my opinion parentheses are already overloaded, so I like to use angle brackets for sequences and square brackets for matrices, but some people use parentheses for all these things.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's just because I have already used the bra-kets for average values, and I guess that some misunderstanding might arise by using the same notation for sequences... Thanks :)